# toFixed onBlur not wanting to fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to make the number entered auto shift to 2 decimal places - but after several attempts I can't get this to go - and ideas?:

html

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="null"></td>
    <td class="label">Money Accounted For</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="moneyAccountedFor" id="moneyAccountedFor" tabindex="7" /></td>
</tr>
```

JQuery

```
$("#moneyAccountedFor").blur(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).value.toFixed(2));
    });
```

**Edit:**
To take a look at my problem more closely - I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drewwyatt/AEWHs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.value` instead of `$(this).value`:

```
$("#moneyAccountedFor").blur(function() {
    this.value = this.value.toFixed(2);
});
```

Or `$(this).val()` if you like it more jQuery'ish.

**Update**

The further problem sits on the input value type. You need to parse its value as integer via `parseFloat`, `parseInt` or **[else](http://jsperf.com/performance-of-parseint/14)**...

```
$("#moneyAccountedFor").blur(function() {
    this.value = parseInt(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AEWHs/2/

Comment: That does not appear to work either - am I crazy? http://jsfiddle.net/drewwyatt/AEWHs/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="null"></td>
    <td class="label">Money Accounted For</td>
    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="moneyAccountedFor" id="moneyAccountedFor" onblur ="this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(2)"></td>
</tr>
```

Fiddle here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/drewwyatt/AEWHs/1/